# Convergent series of positive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

I got stuck on this problem while preparing for an exam:

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ be a convergent series of positive terms. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^{\frac{n}{n+1}}<\infty$.

There is a hint that suggests examining the set $S=\{n : a_n^{1/(n+1)}\leq 1/2\}$ but I am not sure how this helps. I was thinking of partitioning $\mathbb{N}$ into countably many sets by changing the fraction in $S$ but I am not sure if this is the right direction to go. I would just love a hint to get started. Thanks in advance

Comment: just to make sure, in your definition of $S$ the exponent is $1/n + 1$ or $1/(n+1)$?

Comment: I just edited it. Hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $a_n^{\frac 1 {n+1}} \leq \frac 1 2$ then $a_n^{\frac n {n+1}}\leq \frac 1 {2^{n}}$ and if $a_n^{\frac 1 {n+1}}  >\frac  1 2$ then $a_n^{\frac n {n+1}} \leq 2 a_n$. Hence $a_n^{\frac n {n+1}} \leq 2a_n+\frac  1 {2^{n}}$ for all $n$. From this it follows that $\sum a_n^{\frac n {n+1}} <\infty$.

Comment: Amazing proof! +1